# How do I set a proxy after runtime

Tags: java, proxy, minecraft

I am making a Minecraft mod, and I need to be able to make the JVM use a proxy while sending all the packets to the Minecraft servers and what-not. I basically need to be able to set the `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` arguments at any time that I need to.

I have not come here empty handed, and I have tried multiple things, one of these being just using `System.setProperty` like this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", getProxyHost());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", getProxyPort());
```

But to no avail, my real IP was still being used to connect.

I also tried to set https proxy information just like the code shown above, but with `https` instead of `http`.

I know that the proxies work, and that this is possible, because I used this batch file to run Minecraft, and the proxies worked perfectly:

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -Xmx800m -jar Minecraft.exe`

Whenever connecting to a server after running minecraft like shown above, the server console and just anything to do with my IP was now using the proxy, now before you go asking `Well why don't you just use the batch file to run your Minecraft with a proxy?`

Know that I want to be able to change this at any point, without having to turn off Minecraft, and then turn it back on, I want to be able to have a menu where I can just input the proxy host and proxy port and then be able to use that.

Thank you for any help that you may give me.

Comment: You never set the https proxy host & port. Does your mod/Minecraft use HTTPS URLs?

Comment: @hichris123 What exactly do you mean by HTTPS URLs?

Comment: Mmm, I'm betting Minecraft works over TLS/HTTPS. Try using the HTTPS proxy settings too (`System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", getProxyHost());`, etc). HTTPS URLs are just URLs with https in the front instead of http, like `https://google.com` instead of `http://google.com`. They transfer content over [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (basically think of it as an encryption between your computer and the server).

Comment: @hichris123 Just tried that, and it still doesn't seem to be working.